# Nginx - ошибка при рестарте

Tags: nginx

Установил на удаленный сервак nginx.
создал файл в nginx/sites-available с названием crm

```
server {
server_name yourdomainorip.com;

access_log off;

location /static/ {
    alias /opt/myenv/static/;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
}
}
```

И в файл nginx.conf происходит include моего файла из директории sites-enabled (была создана ссылка на файл из директории sites-available). B когда пытаюсь перезапустить nginx мне выходит такая ошибка

```
[emerg] unknown 'server' variable
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: include файла происходит ведь в директиве `http`?

Comment: Где-то опечатка. Ищите где у вас используется переменная `$server`.

Comment: Кстати, переменная `$server_name` обычно используется только в логах. Чаще всего нужна не эта переменная, а `$host`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что нужно соблюдать иерархию nginx. Блок *server* всегда внутри *http*.

```
http {
    server {
         location / {
         }
    }
}
```

Подробнее написано в документации на официальном [сайте](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html).